# How to cancel this Queued BackGroundworker

Tags: c#, queue, backgroundworker, legacy-code

I have this bit of legacy code that's been sitting in the code-base and being used for the last couple of years, recently we found that its method **StopImmediately()** doesn't stop it at all. I cant make head nor tail of how it works as I've done very little with threads or background workers.

I was wondering if any of the experienced threading fellas could tell me how to stop this confusing little beast from completing its task. Below is the complete class (sorry for the amount of code)

I cannot figure out how to cancel it .. thanks in advance for any help ..

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Threading;
namespace GPS2.BackgroundWorkerEx
{
public class QedBackgroundWorker
{
    public QedBackgroundWorker() {}

    Queue<object> Queue = new Queue<object>();          
    object lockingObject1 = new object();
    private Thread currentThread;
    public delegate void WorkerCompletedDelegate<K>(K result, Exception error);
    public object Arguments { get; set; }


    /// <summary>    
    /// doWork is a method with one argument    
    /// </summary>    
    /// <typeparam name="T">is the type of the input parameter</typeparam>    
    /// <typeparam name="K">is the type of the output result</typeparam>    
    /// <param name="inputArgument"></param>    
    /// <param name="doWork"></param>    
    /// <param name="workerCompleted"></param>    
     public void RunAsync<T,K>(Func<T, K> doWork, T inputArgument, WorkerCompletedDelegate<K> workerCompleted)    
     {        
         BackgroundWorker bw = GetBackgroundWorker<T,K>(doWork, workerCompleted);

         Queue.Enqueue(new QueueItem(bw, inputArgument));        
         lock (lockingObject1)        
         {            
             if (Queue.Count == 1)            
             {                
                 ((QueueItem)this.Queue.Peek()).RunWorkerAsync();
                 //currentThread = System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread; 
             }        
         }    
     }    
    /// <summary>    
    /// Use this method if you don't need to handle when the worker is completed    
    /// </summary>    
    /// <param name="doWork"></param>    
    /// <param name="inputArgument"></param>    
     public void RunAsync<T,K>(Func<T, K> doWork, T inputArgument)    
     {        
         RunAsync(doWork, inputArgument, null);    
     }

    private BackgroundWorker GetBackgroundWorker<T, K>(Func<T, K> doWork, WorkerCompletedDelegate<K> workerCompleted)    
    {
        BackgroundWorker bw = new BackgroundWorker();

        bw.WorkerReportsProgress = false;        
        bw.WorkerSupportsCancellation = true;        
        bw.DoWork += (sender, args) =>{            
            if (doWork != null)  
            {
                args.Result = (K)doWork((T)args.Argument);
                currentThread = System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread; 
            }        
        };        

        bw.RunWorkerCompleted += (sender, args) =>{            
            if (workerCompleted != null)            
            {                
                workerCompleted((K)args.Result, args.Error);            
            }            

            Queue.Dequeue();            

            lock (lockingObject1)            
            {                
                if (Queue.Count > 0)                
                {                    
                    ((QueueItem)this.Queue.Peek()).RunWorkerAsync();                                  
                }            
            }        
        };        
        return bw;    
    }
    public void StopImmediately()
    {
        if (currentThread != null)
            currentThread.Abort();
    }


    public bool IsBusy()
    {
        ThreadState state = currentThread.ThreadState;
        bool res = true;
        switch (state)
        {
            case ThreadState.Running:
                res =  true;
                break;
            default:
                res =  false;
                break;
        }
        return res;
    }

}
public class QueueItem{    


    public QueueItem(BackgroundWorker backgroundWorker, object argument)    
    {        

        this.BackgroundWorker = backgroundWorker;        
        this.Argument = argument;    
    }    

    public object Argument { get; private set; }    
    public BackgroundWorker BackgroundWorker { get; private set; }    

    public void RunWorkerAsync()    
    {        
        this.BackgroundWorker.RunWorkerAsync(this.Argument);    
    }    

}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

The typical way for a `BackgroundWorker` to support cancellation is for the `DoWork` event handler to periodically check for the `BackgroundWorker`'s `CancellationPending` property:

```
var worker = new BackgroundWorker();
worker.WorkerSupportsCancellation = true;  
worker.DoWork += (sender, args) =>
{            
    foreach (var thing in listOfThingsToDo)
    {
       if (worker.CancellationPending)
       {
            // Someone has asked us to stop doing our thing
            break;
       }
       else
       {
            DoTheThing(thing);
       }
    }
};
```

Someone who wanted to cancel this `BackgroundWorker`, if it were running, would call

```
worker.CancelAsync();
```

which would cause it to set its `CancellationPending` property to `true` and cause the `DoWork` event handler that's currently running to break out of its loop *after it finished processing the current `thing`*. It wouldn't terminate immediately; the thing doing the work has to periodically ask "should I quit now or keep going?" Either way, the worker thread terminates gracefully.

The code written above tries to terminate the background worker immediately by aborting the thread. [This is usually not the way that you want to do it.](http://www.interact-sw.co.uk/iangblog/2004/11/12/cancellation) Ideally, this code should be changed so that the functions passed in as the `doWork` parameter regularly check for a cancellation request.

But the main reason that it doesn't work as written is that the `currentThread` member is not set until *after* the `doWork` function is invoked:

```
bw.DoWork += (sender, args) =>
{
    if (doWork != null)
    {
        args.Result = (K)doWork((T)args.Argument);
        currentThread = System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread;
    }
};
```

A call to `StopImmediately()` would see a null thread, because the `DoWork` callback is waiting for the function passed in as `doWork` to finish before it assigns the `currentThread` member.

They should be flipped as follows

```
bw.DoWork += (sender, args) =>
{
    if (doWork != null)
    {
        currentThread = System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread;
        args.Result = (K)doWork((T)args.Argument);
    }
};
```

and then it will indeed terminate uncleanly and (more or less) immediately. I recommend reading [this MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc221403%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) for an example of how to better approach supporting cancellation in a `BackgroundWorker`.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Cheers that does help .. in Fact this one line "Ideally, this code should be changed so that the functions passed in as the doWork parameter regularly checks for a cancellation request." I changed the runAsync<> method to return a BackGroundWorker BGWrk, added 'cancellation' handling in the 'passed in' function and then used the returned BGWrk.CancelAsync() ... I hope that's correct as it seems to work just dandy.